# Using `link_to` to Update Boolean in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have read many similar SO posts but can't find one that solves the routing error I'm having here.  I'm making a basic wiki-type app and when a user downgrades from `premium` to `standard` (changing the boolean value for `user.premium?` to `false`), I want this action to also change the booleans for all their `wikis` so `wiki.private?` is `false`. The link is on the `devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` page:

```
<h3>Change My Account Type</h3>
  <% if current_user.premium %>
    <p><%= link_to "Downgrade my account from premium.", downgrade_user_path(current_user), confirm: "Are you sure?" %></p>
  <% else %>
    <p><%= link_to "Upgrade to premium!", new_charge_path %>
  <% end %>
```

And here is the `users_controller`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @wikis = current_user.wikis
    @private_wikis = @wikis.where(private: true)
    @public_wikis = @wikis.where(private: false)
  end

  def downgrade
    @wikis = current_user.wikis
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:premium, false)
    @wikis.each do |wiki|
      wiki.update_attribute(:private, false)
    end 
  end
end
```

And here is the route:

```
match "users/:id/downgrade" => "users#downgrade", :as => "downgrade_user", via: [:get, :post]
```

The action successfully downgrades the user, but I get a missing template error when trying to make all the private `wikis` public:

```
Missing template users/downgrade, application/downgrade with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}.
```

This makes me think it's something with the routing that is going wrong.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you do all the business logic for downgrading a user, what do you want to do?

```
  def downgrade
    @wikis = current_user.wikis
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:premium, false)
    @wikis.each do |wiki|
      wiki.update_attribute(:private, false)
    end
    redirect_to user_registration_path
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, ideally just see the user registration edit page again.

Comment: Ok, then go ahead and add that at the end of your _downgrade_ action.

Comment: Ahhh!  Perfect.  Thank you!